# What is the short story about a computer program that employers use to micromanage every aspect of a worker's life?

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I once read a short story about someone inventing a computer program which starts off just scheduling workers, but ends up controlling every aspect of a worker's life. Eventually, every worker is reduced to a mechanical automaton controlled by this earpiece, and lives in identical cell-like structures. All aspects of free thought are eventually eliminated as time goes on.

However, while the way the software is used in the protagonist's country is dystopian, in other parts of the world the same or similar software is used to liberate working people and bring about an age of economic liberation allowing them to pursue their dreams.

I'm not sure who the author was, but I believe it's from the 1960s or perhaps beyond.

Comment: You are perhaps thinking of real life from 2020 onwards.

Comment: I can think at least of Matrix, Twelve Monkeys, The Life and Times of Multivac and The Machine Stops. None of them matches specifically the description tho

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Manna](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manna_(novel)) by Marshall Brain. From the wiki article:

> The fictional story is set on an unspecified date in the future and begins in Cary, North Carolina. The narrator recalls his first minimum wage job at Burger-G fast food joint in the early 21st century, and describes the Manna system, which was installed there as a simple store management tool that guided the minimum-wage workers via headset.

> After Manna finally takes over his current education job he is forced into a massive, cheaply built government welfare housing project, with little hope of regaining employment or escaping.

> After a year in the housing projects he is visited by two women who tell him that because his father bought stock in the Australia Project years prior, he's invited to live in Australia, an advanced society with Universal Basic Income. The narrator leaves the dystopian United States for Australia, and goes on to learn about, and live in, the Australia Project.

You can read the whole story on author Marshal Brain's [own website](https://marshallbrain.com/manna).

Comment: remarkably scary for a story without, say, a monster. plausible.

Comment: @releseabe: I cannot recommend "Meditations on Moloch" strongly enough.

Comment: Yes thank you this is the one I was thinking about.

Comment: And wiki link has a link to the author's own website where you can read the story. So I've submitted an edit to your your answer to include this.  T

Comment: Wow. What a story.

Comment: Thanks @PreetSangha!