# Where can I find "The Device" by Emily W?

Tags: short-stories, science-fiction-genre

The story follows a young woman named Elizabeth Cartwright who acquires a job position at one of the most influential companies in the world, Ambivalent Communications. When she arrives at the building she sees dozens of workers in plain uniform with their heads hunched down, eyes glued to their devices. Every time she approaches a worker to ask where she can go to the main office she is met with annoyance and a cold swerve in the other direction.

When she finally steps into the main office, the boss hands her a device, the same one every other worker is so entranced by, and when she tries to thank him, he loudly remarks that she needs to talk only through her device. The device is known by the acronym PLACID* (Performance-Level A_____ I______ Device).

The device gives workers all of the information they will need from where and when their next meeting/ task is to how they can get to their destinations, provided with codes to unlock specific doors or elevators. As Elizabeth heads out of the office she bumps into a worker, causing her device to fall to the ground and stop functioning. Embarrassed and disheartened by the event, she remembers advice from her grandmother, who told her to be true to herself and values. She decides that she does not belong at Ambivalent Communications because it does not align with her value of physical communication and heads for the exit. As the sun hits her face and she's about to leave for good, she hears the siren calls of her PLACID device, informing her that it has repaired itself and that she should head to the elevator to get to her next meeting. Instantly, she is captured and compelled by the device and turns back toward the elevator.

The story ends with her believing that she does in fact belong at Ambivalent Communications as she has become the same as all of the other workers - heads faced down at the ground, eyes locked to their devices, and the belief that they are a part of the communication of the future.

*I can't remember the entire acronym for the device.

Comment: Where did you read this? Never mind a PDF, outside of your question, I can't any information about this story whatsoever.

Comment: It seems like we're getting a lot of questions https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/274474/short-story-involving-a-broken-pda-that-results-in-freedom  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/274632/what-is-the-short-story-about-a-computer-program-that-employers-use-to-micromana about stories about PDA-like devices taking over the world!  It sounds like this isn't any of those though.